# Train and test data split in r but not randomly

Tags: r, train-test-split

I want to split data in training ans testing but not randomly. I want first 80% of rows should be treated as training and rest as testing.

```
rows=nrow(data)
index=0.80*row
train=data[1:index]
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `data[1:index, ]`

Comment: @ngm And what will be for test?

Comment: Use the `caret` package https://dataanalyticsblog.com/tag/train-test-split-in-r.

Comment: `data[-(1:index),]` for testing